# Extract flag and its value from string

Tags: bash

I want to be able to extract a flag (-q) and its value from a string. An example:

`<string1> -q <value> <string2>`

Here, `<string1>` and `<string2>` **can contain any set of characters**. To clarify `<string1>` and `<string2>` are **placeholders** for any possible string.

I want two things:

1. Be able to get the string 
   `<string1> <string2>`
2. Be able to get the string `<value>`

I would also be able to do something similar for this input:

`<string1> --all <string2>`

where `--all` is extracted and `<string1> <string2>` is is kept.

Unlike the proposed solution in [How do I parse command line arguments in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash), I want to be able to extract a flag and its value and then keep the original command line input without the flag and that value.

Comment: Are you actually trying to parse command-line arguments?

Comment: Yes, I am. Normally all strings entered to my script are not using flags. So basically I am simply parsing e.g. $1, $2, etc. The reason for this is that my script is supposed to increase productivity for entering similar commands over and over and entering flags takes too much time.

Comment: For given input below one should work, your question should be more informative, for more answers.

    `$ echo '<string1> --all <string2>' | grep -Po "(?<=<string1>).*(?=\s*<string2>)"`

Comment: @tripleee That duplicate does not answer how to extract the values from an existing string.

Comment: Just assign the string to `$@` with `set` or similar.

Comment: @tripleee Yeah it worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

A quick and very simple solution using `cut`:

```
 echo "<string1> -q value <string2>" | cut -d'>' -f2 | cut -d'<' -f1
```

outputs :  -q value

**NOTE** this only works if whatever is between your string1 / string2 tags does not contain <>

Comment: >Here, <string1> and <string2> can contain any set of characters.
So, for example "echo "asd qweqwe adssad  -q value qwewqe asdasdasd qweqweewq asdasd" | cut -d'>' -f2 | cut -d'<' -f1" will not work

Comment: @toerq if the value you passed is between the string1 string 2 tags, it works. :  `echo "<string1>asd qweqwe adssad -q value qwewqe asdasdasd qweqweewq asdasd<string2>" | cut -d'>' -f2 | cut -d'<' -f1` in your comments you missed the string1/2 tags in the echo